# Django Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Error Due to INSTALLED_APPS in Settings

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Django application through the Elastic Beanstalk CLI but have an error with an app I include in the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file. Here's the layout of my django project:

```
django3 
     |--- manage.py
     |--- requirements.txt
     |--- .ebextensions
           |--- 01_python.config
     |--- appone
           |--- migrations
                 |--- __init__.py
           |--- templates
                 |--- index.html
           |--- __init__.py
           |--- admin.py
           |--- apps.py
           |--- forms.py
           |--- models.py
           |--- tests.py
           |--- urls.py
           |--- views.py
    |--- django3
           |--- __init__.py
           |--- asgi.py
           |--- settings.py
           |--- urls.py
           |--- wsgi.py
```

When I run the django project locally everything works fine, but when I attempt to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appone'
```

This is preceded in the logs at some point with these lines:

```
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
```

so it seems it's attempting to make an entry for the appone app but the name for it in the apps.py I have is incorrect. My apps.py file is this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApponeConfig(AppConfig):
    #default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'appone'
```

And my settings.py file INSTALLED_APPS is this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'appone'
]
```

I found some similar issues like this one:
[Django : Can't import 'module'. Check that module AppConfig.name is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177499/django-cant-import-module-check-that-module-appconfig-name-is-correct)
but none of the suggested answers work for me (switching name = 'appone' to  name = 'django3.appone' in the apps.py file causes both my local version and the elastic beanstalk deployment to fail).

Comment: Have you tried adding in `INSTALLED_APPS`  >  `appone.apps.ApponeConfig` ?

Comment: I still get the same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appone' in the logs, which is preceded by app_config = AppConfig.create(entry) so it's still the same cause it seems like. This code also works for my local version though, so it's just a problem when I deploy it through Elastic Beanstalk (just like my original code was).

Comment: My previous comment was me replacing appone with appone.apps.ApponeConfig, if I put both of them into INSTALLED_APPS then I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apponeappone'. This time it doesn't work for my local version or the Elastic Beanstalk deployment.

Comment: I realized that my zip file wasn't being made correctly since it had a folder inside of it (I had django3 zip, with django3 inside of it), so once I correctly just had the zip file with all the folders and files directly inside of it my original approach worked.